# Using inherited assignment operator

Tags: c++

I have the following classes:

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    double a, b;
public:
    Shape(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    double area() const { return a*b; }

    Shape operator+(const Shape & other)
    {
        Shape temp(0, 0);
        temp.a = a + other.a;
        temp.b = b + other.b;
        return temp;
    }
    void operator=(const Shape & other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(int a, int b) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    double area() { return a*b/2; }
    Triangle(int a, int b) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
};
```

Is it sensible to use inherited operator= in Rectangle and Triangle class?
Using it I can assign Shape to Rectangle or Triangle or even Triangle to Rectangle:

```
Rectangle r(1, 1);
Triangle t(1, 1);
r = t; // OK
```

Is it even sensible to do so in general?

Comment: How come your `Triangle` is defined by only two numbers?

Comment: if there's a useful case for this I'd say go for it but I can't see a sensible reason why you would want to.

Comment: @dedObed If it's always a right-angled triangle, then that's OK!

Comment: `a`/`b` are meaningless, `width`/`height` seems better.

Comment: It seems some `virtual` are missing, Triangle t(3, 4), const Shape& s = t;` then `s.area() != t.area()`. But Your Shape abstraction seems strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not sensible.

First, your `Shape::operator=` is not doing anything that the compiler generated assignment could not do also:

```
struct Shape {
    double a, b;
    Shape(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    double area() const { return a*b; }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Rectangle(int a, int b) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
};

struct Triangle : Shape {
    double area() { return a*b/2; }
    Triangle(int a, int b) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
};

int main(){
    Rectangle r(1, 1);
    Triangle t(1, 1);
    r = t;              // OK  !!!
}
```

In your example there is literally no difference between a `Rectangle` and a `Triangle` (their `area` aside). Problems arise when you make `Triangle` have 3 members (you need them to represent a triangle):

```
#include <cassert>

struct Shape {
    double a, b;
    Shape(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    double area() const { return a*b; }
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
    Rectangle(int a, int b) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
};

struct Triangle : Shape {
    double area() { return a*b/2; }
    Triangle(int a, int b,int c) : Shape(a, b) {  }
    using Shape::operator=;
    double c;
};

int main(){
    Rectangle r(1, 2);
    Triangle t(1, 1, 2);
    Triangle t2(1,2,3);
    r = t;                   // OK
    t2 = r;
    assert( t.c == t2.c);        // should be fine, no?
}
```

After `r = t;` and `t2 = r;` an innocent reader does expect that `t == t2;` but it isn't. A rectangle is not a triangle and a triangle is not a rectangle. If you really want to make such conversion possible you better define it `explicit`.